# Records in which entity MS CRM 2011 creates as part of sharing process?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm automatically sharing records in MS CRM 2011 on specific users and teams using custom rules. But users are able to alter this sharing information using button on MS CRM ribbon, and this will spoil all the security model I have.

I believe should be a way to prevent this information from being updated by using plugin on server side. But I'm not aware `Update` event on which entity I should listen to capture this edit event?

Records in which entity are created when user shares an entity?

Comment: Are you aware of the drawbacks of using sharing to drive the security model? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukcrm/archive/2011/07/08/automating-crm-2011-security-rules-with-plug-ins.aspx

Comment: Thanks! But what else shell I do, if I need to implement complex model that does not fit standard?

Comment: Teams will usually do the trick, gets a little heavy on the administration side of things but is often the best option.

Comment: It's approach with the teams: I need to implement security model with three hierarchies of business units in the same time. It's done by creating respective teams and sharing on them.

Answer (score 3):

Is not a reply to your question, but:

the users can share only if they have rights to do.

This can be defined inside the security roles

[image]

and if you are sharing a record programmatically you can set also if a user has the share privilege or not (as similar when you set by UI):

[image]

Comment: I'm more afraid if user unchecks `Read` checkbox in your illustration and will press `OK`. Since in this case one user will lose access to the record.

Comment: If the user doesn't have the Share permission, then the Share button on the toolbar shouldn't even be visible, so they'd never get to this screen to uncheck the Read checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Total stab in the dark, but I believe the [GrantAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.grantaccessrequest.aspx) message is what you need.

It looks like whenever a user attempts to give access via sharing (haven't tested it yet) the plugin should fire and you can check to see if they have rights, and cancel the request.

It [only works on user owned entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx), which is what I'm assuming yours is.

And you may need to register for RevokeAccess as well if they are "Unsharing"

Comment: Yes, probably you're right, but is there any example how to create plugin for `GrantAccess` message? I'm trying to create plugin but it don't want to fire, no matter what I do. If primary entity should be `user` or `team` and secondary is the the entity I trying to give user access to — it's impossible to set `systemuser` as primary. If I'm setting `lead` as primary and granting access to the lead event don't fire either.

Comment: Not that tempting as it sounds. What does `user-owned` term means? Does it means that plugin will fire only if I'm granting access to the record assigned to me, or to any user? I believe by `user-owned` entities they mean entities can be owned by any user. In opposite to the `system-owned`, like `PrincipalObjectAccess` that cannot be assigned to the user.

Comment: @shytikov It's the option that you have when you create the entity.   I think you have the understanding correct.  You can also see when giving a role rights to the entity, you only have the empty circle and fully green circle as options since it is not owned by a user it can't be a part of the business unit parent child ownership hierarchy and there for you don't see the yellow pie slice option, or half green circle or almost fully green circle.

Comment: actually it seems that `GrantAccess` works on every entity. Not even assigned to me. But I will finish the code and inform you about results.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, `GrantAccess` fires on every entity, no matter to whom it assigned.  `PrincipalAccess` object is among `PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters`.